# IOS ошибка параметра (Swift3, Twitter, Fabric, urlRequest)

Tags: ios, request, twitter-api, swift3

В ios новичок. Нужно с твитом отправить массив айдишников медиа. Вылезает ошибка, не могу понять почему, пример тоже не нашел.

```
2016-10-27 13:42:57.244 Twishort[89387:28692145] error saving session: Error Domain=TWTRGenericKeychainItemErrorDomain Code=-34018 "Error Code: -34018: Unknown Keychain error code." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error Code: -34018: Unknown Keychain error code.}
2016-10-27 13:43:06.553 Twishort[89387:28680054] -[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000039620
2016-10-27 13:43:06.561 Twishort[89387:28680054] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Swift._SwiftDeferredNSArray stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000039620'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fed434b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f93521e objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010ff43f34 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 132
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe59c15 ___forwarding___ + 1013
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe59798 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120
    5   Twishort                            0x000000010b733c7f +[TWTRNetworkingUtil percentEscapedQueryStringWithString:encoding:] + 117
    6   Twishort                            0x000000010b733adb +[TWTRNetworkingUtil queryStringFromParameters:] + 425
    7   Twishort                            0x000000010b72591c -[TwitterNetworking URLRequestWithMethod:URL:parameters:] + 187
    8   Twishort                            0x000000010b7779f3 -[TWTRAPIClient URLRequestWithMethod:URL:parameters:error:] + 127
    9   Twishort                            0x000000010b705614 _TFC8Twishort6PostVC11sendTwitterfT10resultTextSS6clientCSo13TWTRAPIClient_T_ + 1300
    10  Twishort                            0x000000010b705031 _TFC8Twishort6PostVC7twitterfT10resultTextSS_T_ + 817
    11  Twishort                            0x000000010b704ada _TFFC8Twishort6PostVC12sendTwishortFT_T_U_FGV9Alamofire12DataResponseP__T_ + 2874
    12  Alamofire                           0x000000010bd94f59 _TFFFC9Alamofire11DataRequest8responseuRxS_30DataResponseSerializerProtocolrFT5queueGSqCSo13DispatchQueue_18responseSerializerx17completionHandlerFGVS_12DataResponsewx16SerializedObject_T__DS0_U_FT_T_U_FT_T_ + 889
    13  Alamofire                           0x000000010bd94fb7 _TTRGRx9Alamofire30DataResponseSerializerProtocolrXFo___XFdCb___ + 39
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112c86980 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112cb00cd _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000112c908d6 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 406
    17  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe984f9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe5df8d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010fe5d494 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
    20  GraphicsServices                    0x000000011270aa6f GSEventRunModal + 161
    21  UIKit                               0x000000010e0e7f34 UIApplicationMain + 159
    22  Twishort                            0x000000010b6fff9f main + 111
    23  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000112cfc68d start + 1
    24  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
2016-10-27 13:43:07.868626 Twishort[89387:28693304] [] nw_endpoint_flow_protocol_connected [9.1 199.16.156.52:443 in_progress socket-flow (satisfied)] Output protocol connected
```

Я так понимаю проблема в `as [String : Any]`, потому что `let parameters = ["media_ids": idImage! as String]` заходит нормально..

```
func sendTwitter(resultText: String, client: TWTRAPIClient) {
        let statusesShowEndpointUpdate = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
        let parameters = ["status": resultText, "media_ids": [idImage! as String]] as [String : Any]
//        let parameters = ["media_ids": idImage! as String]
        var clientError : NSError?

        let requestUpdate = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: statusesShowEndpointUpdate, parameters: parameters, error: &clientError)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(requestUpdate) { (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if connectionError != nil {
                print("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }

            do {
                self.textField.text = ""
                let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: [])
                print("json: \(json)")
            } catch let jsonError as NSError {
                print("json error: \(jsonError.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: В параметрах должен быть дикшенари стринг к стрингу. ДУмаю, что надо юзать uploadMedia: для загрузки картинки

Comment: Так если media_ids это массив id media, как параметр будет стрингами?
uploadMedia раньше использую, idMedia это строка с id

Comment: А, ну тогда надо читать спецификацию апи, там скорее всего просто через запятую их надо забить. componentsJoinedByString по тому массиву попробуй

Comment: Тоже так подумал, потому что просто строку вместо в массива он в итоге съел. Позже попробую

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в "unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x608000039620", то есть неопознанном селекторе.

Скорее всего в названии метода "POST"

```
let requestUpdate = client.urlRequest(withMethod: "POST", url: statusesShowEndpointUpdate, parameters: parameters, error: &clientError)
```